# Where is the Unix script command in Cygwin?

Tags: shell, cygwin

Iirc, the [Unix script command](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~gini/1901-07s/files/script.html) used to be in cygwin. Does anyone know what happened to it or where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`util-linux`](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64/util-linux/util-linux-2.25.2-2&grep=util-linux) (for at least the past 4 years, it seems):

```
2015-03-23 08:47       18963 usr/bin/script.exe
2015-03-23 08:47       14355 usr/bin/scriptreplay.exe
```